# Running new electrical with drywall removed, but insulation installed

Tags: electrical, drywall, insulation

I had to pull a 4' high and long section of drywall out of my garage due to a ton of damage in various places.

While that's off, I'm planning to lower the electrical boxes along that wall about 3 feet. I'm just going to drill new holes through the studs and run it like brand new electrical basically.

The trouble is, these walls are already completed in the sense that there's batt insulation existing and stapled into place.

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to work around the insulation to drill the holes for the new electrical, staple them to the wall running down into the new boxes (and install the new boxes for that matter).

Or am I better off just removing sections of insulation across the new area, running all the wire and installing boxes, then patching insulation in those areas?

Comment: Any idea why the receptacles were installed high in the first place?  Is that a local Code requirement? Flooding issue?  Not having to stoop to reach a plug (always a pain)?

Comment: My garage receptacles are all about 4 ft off the floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find batt insulation easy to pull out and re-install. Drilling near existing fiberglass (guessing that is what you have) can lead to strands getting caught in the bit and spinning.

I recommend pull out the batts of insulation, do the electrical work and they reinstall the same batts you pulled.

Also assuming you have vapor barrier or retarder on the face (probably what the staples are in), you can try saving the vapor barrier but it may rip. Just add another layer of Kraft paper or 6 mil poly sheeting to replace the old stuff.

Comment: Note that vapor barrier on the inside is a bad idea anywhere AC is in use, as it serves as an impermeable condensing surface/moisture trap, leading to mold.